# Why some styles does not apply to email template?

Tags: html, css

I have really basic html template with simple styles.
Something like that:

```css
 .wrap{
            display:flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .child{
            display: flex;
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
            border-radius: 50%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class='wrap'>
        <div class="child">0</div>
        <div class="child">1</div>
        <div class="child">2</div>
        <div class="child">3</div>
        <div class="child">4</div>
        <div class="child">5</div>
        <div class="child">6</div>
        <div class="child">7</div>
        <div class="child">8</div>
        <div class="child">9</div>
        <div class="child">10</div>
    </div>
```

In short way, when I am checking my email, The wrap is flex but does not have justify-content.
Same case with .child, I see circles with color etc but, the child do not have:

```css
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: You should [avoid using `flex` in email templates](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/). Code it like it's year 1990. Table layouts are usually the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

you need to try to do it inline Stylesheet, as reference all emails providers don't take into consideration the classes style format. the best practice is to use inline

let me know if it work

Comment: Unfortunately not, I put all my styles in inline and I have the same result, I can't see justify from .wrap and justify and align from .child

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of how it looks like in your email? because i think the problem is flex doesn't apply

Comment: I found out gmail etc doesn't support new methods styling like flex or grid, So i need to style them in old way by using table etc. For all my programming life I was using flex, so na I can't style them as i want without flex

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, check your css file you have not apply css to `.html` file properly.

Comment: 1. You can see 90% of styles have been loaded.
2. You can see all styles naming is correct
3. So it's not a problem with css

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).